# Use an external library in rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a node (rosjava) that uses the library "lejos".
Node compile without error, but when I run the node

```
rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py nxt_rosjava org.ros.nxt_rosjava.Listener
```

I get an error

```
Buildfile: /home/alex/lego-nxt-car-like/nxt_rosjava/dependencies.xml

get-dependencies:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
Executing command: ['java', '-classpath', u'/home/alex/lego-nxt-car-like/nxt_rosjava/target/org.ros.rosjava.nxt_rosjava-0.0.0.jar:/home/alex/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.test_ros-0.0.0.jar:/home/alex/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.roscpp-0.0.0.jar:/home/alex/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.topic_tools-0.0.0.jar:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc/target/org.ros.rosjava.apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3.jar:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/target/org.ros.rosjava.rosjava_bootstrap-0.0.0.jar:/home/alex/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.std_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava/target/org.ros.rosjava-0.0.0.jar:/home/alex/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.rosgraph_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/home/alex/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.geometry_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/rosjava_core/apache_commons_util/target/org.ros.rosjava.ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/org.ros.rosjava.guava/r07/org.ros.rosjava.guava-r07.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/dnsjava/org.ros.rosjava.dnsjava/2.1.1/org.ros.rosjava.dnsjava-2.1.1.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec/1.3.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec-1.3.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging/1.1.1/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/alex/.m2/repository/org/jboss/netty/netty/3.2.4.Final/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar', 'org.ros.RosRun', 'org.ros.nxt_rosjava.Listener']
Loading node class: org.ros.nxt_rosjava.Listener
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lejos/nxt/Motor
    at org.ros.nxt_rosjava.Listener.main(Listener.java:36)
    at org.ros.RosRun.main(RosRun.java:71)
```

I think that I need add "/home/alex/lejos_nxj/lib/pc/pccomm.jar" in dependencies.xml, but how    to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11325/use-an-external-library-in-rosjava/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2011-09-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-10-11**:
I realize this is solved, but I wrote a quick tutorial for what worked for me. it may be of some use for someone else. [http://coe.uncc.edu/~acharris/How_To_ROSJAVA/ROSJAVA_Tutorial.html](http://coe.uncc.edu/%7Eacharris/How_To_ROSJAVA/ROSJAVA_Tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add the path of the jar file in manifest.xml in the rosjava_pathelement tag. And you also need to add the path in ros.properties to the classpath and jarfileset properties. Take care to use the right delimiter (, vs :).

Edit:
So my procedure to include external (i.e. non-ros) jar files now is:

- Create a package, e.g., "external_jar", create subfolder, put jar-files there
- Add a rosjava_pathelement tag with the relative path to each jar file to external_jar's manifest.xml (see other rosjava manifest.xml files for exact syntax)
- Declare dependency on external_jar in manifest of the package where the jar-files are needed.
- Rosmake your package

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-10-07**:
Ok, now I got it to build. But have a running problem, which probably requires its own post. Thanks for the help!!!

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2011-10-06**:
I build project in Eclipse. Before build I add the path of the jar file in ros.properties to the ros.compile.classpath and ros.compile.jarfileset properties.If I launch "rosmake" then those properties erase and I need to add again.

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-10-05**:
I'm doing something similar and having problems. Even when I add the  to my manifest.xml, my builds keep failing because it can't find the imports for the new library. This is a completely non-ROS library I'm adding so "depend" doesn't work.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-09-28**:
Great! With the above description you can use the relative location, which makes your package portable to other computers.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2011-09-28**:
Node runs!!! I add "" in manifest.xml and run "rosmake nxt_rosjava". Thank you!

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-09-28**:
Hm, there is more to it, it seems. I'll update this tomorrow